# PHP .htaccess redirect if url contains slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to redirect if url contains slash?
I control it in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

So, if user type http://domain.com/blog/, it will redirect to http://domain.com/blog (without slash /).

Please help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: OK got it, 1 question how can I redirect to folder RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ folder/$1 [R=301,L] <-- is this like that?